# How to disable subscription automatically on connexion lost (PostgreSQL Logical Replication)?

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I am currently working on logical replication (master / slave) with PostgreSQL. It is working very well, but I would like to anticipate the scenario where the connexion is broken unexpectedly (master offline, or socket broken...).

I have found a way to mimic this scenario, and the following logs are produced :

```
2019-10-01 15:05:31.205 GMT [165] ERROR:  could not receive data from WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
2019-10-01 15:05:31.206 GMT [121] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 165) exited with exit code 1
2019-10-01 15:05:31.207 GMT [170] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "sub_2" has started
2019-10-01 15:05:31.207 GMT [170] ERROR:  could not connect to the publisher: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "100.x.x.x" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Now, what I would like to do is find a way to disable the subscription automatically when it happens (ie. execute the following command), then the ERROR will not appear in the logs because the worker will not exist and will not try to connect to an offline master.

```
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION sub2 DISABLE
```

To do that, I see some options but I don't know how to apply them :

1. Catch the ERROR (either in WAL or "logical replication worker")
2. Find a way to execute some code at "logical replication worker" startup
3. Use a CRON (at application level, so not native to PSQL) to check if the server is offline (pulsation). If so, then execute the above command manually. Note that this solution may work but I would like to avoid it because there will still be some errors raised if the connexion is lost between two "ticks" of the CRON

Thank you very much for your help, cheers

Comment: Just leave logical replication running, so that it can reconnect if connectivity is re-established.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes sure it is working, but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution than just letting those error polluting the logs, and this replication worker restarting in loop for nothing.

Comment: In understand your concern. You could run with reduced `log_min_messages` to avoid log spam. I don't think that the overhead of trying to connect regularly is so big. If you disable logical replication, you'll probably have to so something very similar yourself, which won't be any cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for your precious advise. I will stick to that if I don't find any solution then ! :) 
By the way, I have a detecated API for enabling / disabling replication when I want between master and slave (ie. when connexion is made / finished), that's why I wanted to handle the case of unexpectedly connexion lost the same way.

Comment: Just for information, I have chosen the solution 3 and it works pretty good. (ie. use a CRON (at application level, so not native to PSQL) to check if the server is offline (pulsation). If so, then execute the above command manually. Note that this solution may work but I would like to avoid it because there will still be some errors raised if the connexion is lost between two "ticks" of the CRON)